# Increasing Storage Space on EC2 instance AWS to fix Kibana read-only error

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-ec2, kibana, tpot

I am currently using an EC2 instance on AWS to host a network using T-pot and therefore Kibana. I have run out of storage space on the hosted machine, giving this error when trying to load statistical data:

`[esaggs] > EsError: index [.async-search] blocked by: [TOO_MANY_REQUESTS/12/disk usage exceeded flood-stage watermark, index has read-only-allow-delete block];`

I have tried to increase the hard disk space to 250 Gib, by modifying the instance. This seems to have gone ahead smoothly, but whenever I open T-pot, I am still faced with the error despite this increase in storage space

Is this because the EC2 instance hasn't updated? Is it because I need to reconnect the storage space? Or do I just need to shut down and then re-create the server again?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: How have you increased disk space? Just adding more GB on the EC2 volume or you have also extended linux system volume too? When you do `lsblk` you get 250 for your volume?

Comment: I have only done it on the EC2 volume. How do I increase it on my server?

Comment: Have a look at this https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/recognize-expanded-volume-linux.html. Do you get `nvme..` or `xvd..` when you do lsblk?

Comment: I have resolved the error. I simply refreshed the nodes and updated the connections within the kibana toolset. Thanks for the help though